# Is there an adapter to remove locking latches on DisplayPort male connector?

Tags: display-port, cable, adapter

I have a problem with disconnecting DisplayPort cables. Almost all other connection cables are normal, but with dp it is another story. Some dp cables has latches - a locking mechanism. It does not allow you to just pull the cable to unconnect it. You need to press the mechanical button that will release latches.

[image]

This was probably designed for "reliability", but that really brings nothing more than problems! This button is hard to press sometimes, and is inconvenient even when you can do it. And there are situations when you just physically cannot press it, leaving you in locked down position.

In my case, I cannot disconnect dp cable before I remove the DVI cable, see picture:

[image]

I disassembled my cable, and unfortunately, I doubt I could successfully remove that mechanism and then assemble the cable again.

[image]

I know there are cables without latches and I can purchase such to replace mine. But still there are situations when you cannot just replace cable. In my case, the DisplayPort to hdmi adapter also has such latches, and I suffer from this same problem.

So the question is: does such adapter exist that can take a male displayport connector with latches, and output the male displayport but without latches? In other words, can I remove latches by placing adapter and not by modifying the cable itself?

Comment: Although the current answer interprets this in a way it is on-topic, it actually looks more like tech support in my eyes, so I have to close it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the item on AliExpress called "Converter DisplayPort Male to Female". It is for some reason hard to find in search, even when I know the item is in stock, try with the following request: "HD DP Video Converter DP1.4 To DP Female Mini DP Adapter" or "DP-090-A".

[image]

You can "disable" latches by using this adapter. And you do not need to break your existing cables.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note, there is a similar item - dp female to male adapter, that looks like this:
[image]

Do not buy it, because it has latches on itself.

Comment: You mean to place something flat inside the black case? I did not understand what you mean.